# How do I set css classes for a gridview row and header by code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was trying the following but it says that the header row is null?>

```
   private void CreateGridControl()
   {
        lastCreatedOpportunitiesGrid = new GridView();

        BoundField bOportunityCode = new BoundField();
        bOportunityCode.DataField = "OpportunityCode";
        bOportunityCode.HeaderText = "OpportunityCode";
        lastCreatedOpportunitiesGrid.Columns.Add(bOportunityCode);

        BoundField bOpportunityName = new BoundField();
        bOpportunityName.DataField = "OpportunityName";
        bOpportunityName.HeaderText = "OpportunityName";
        lastCreatedOpportunitiesGrid.Columns.Add(bOpportunityName);

        HyperLinkField bCSLink = new HyperLinkField();
        bCSLink.DataNavigateUrlFields = new string[] {"CsLink"};
        bCSLink.HeaderText = "CsLink";
        bCSLink.Text = @"<img src='" + ResolveUrl("/_layouts/15/xx/xx/Images/cs.gif") + "' /> ";
        lastCreatedOpportunitiesGrid.Columns.Add(bCSLink);

        lastCreatedOpportunitiesGrid.HeaderRow.CssClass = Constants.CssClasses.HeaderRow;
        lastCreatedOpportunitiesGrid.RowStyle.CssClass = Constants.CssClasses.Row;
        lastCreatedOpportunitiesGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        lastCreatedOpportunitiesGrid.EmptyDataText = Constants.Messages.NoOpportunitiesFound;

        this.Controls.Add(lastCreatedOpportunitiesGrid);
        LoadGridData();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should be setting `CssClass` in the `HeaderStyle` property:

```
lastCreatedOpportunitiesGrid.HeaderStyle.CssClass = Constants.CssClasses.HeaderRow;
```

The `HeaderRow` property gives you the GridView's header after the databinding. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.headerrow.aspx: "The HeaderRow property is available only after the GridView control creates the header row in the RowCreated event."

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
lastCreatedOpportunitiesGrid.HeaderRow.CssClass = "your_class_name";
```

Comment: you cant do that as I explained the HeaderRow object is null at that moment. Paolo answer solved it